# WSL - My terminal "hangs" for almost one minute between each commands

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, wsl2, vcxsrv

## Context

Since some week I meet a issue with my wsl terminals. It seems to be links to the add of the followings lines in my .zshrc:

```
export DISPLAY_NUMBER="0.0"
export DISPLAY=$(grep -m 1 nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'):$DISPLAY_NUMBER
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

I add this line in order to be able to use desktop environement (xfce4).

## Issue

Whatever command I type (ls, cd, nano...) the result took almost one minute to appear. But I notice something more strange if I press Ctrl+C the result appear instantly but not the prompt, I have to press CTRL+C again if don't I have to wait.

If I remove the lines above and source my .zshrc file I don't see any changes...

## Workaround

The issue not happens when VcXsrv is launched.

Do you have any idea of what could happens? What can I do to display what the terminal is waiting when I'm typing a trivial command and it's hangs?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sounds like something in your prompt is taking a long time.

Comment: @harrymc Is there any way to know which command hang the prompt? It's true that I have some plugins active on my zsh config.

Comment: I think you are right @harrymc without "bgnotify" plugin I don't have the issue. But a source on the zshrc file is not enough. I have to restart wsl.